# how to toggle <div> tags hidden and visible with <span> and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a site with a search bar, but there is too much search content and I need a way for people to toggle it being hidden

```
<div class="search">
<ul><a href="bashEmulator.html">Bash Shell Emulator</a></ul>
<ul><a href="bashShellUseHow.html">How to use bash shell </a></ul>
```

*much more* to this. But how can I toggle it being hidden and it being shown with JS and `<span>`? 
Thank you very much,
Ring Games

Comment: You need hide or show the div when the user click a span?

Comment: When the user clicks span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use toggle to add and remove a class, and with the class you can hide the elements inside the search, this is an example:

```js
const searchElement = document.getElementById("search");
const toggleElement = document.getElementById("toggle-visibility");

toggleElement.addEventListener("click", toggleSearchVisibility);

function toggleSearchVisibility() {
  searchElement.classList.toggle("hide-element")
}
```

```css
.hide-element{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <ul><a href="bashEmulator.html">Bash Shell Emulator</a></ul>
  <ul><a href="bashShellUseHow.html">How to use bash shell </a></ul>
</div>

<span id="toggle-visibility">Click me!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you use the JQuery library. Its super easy, all you need to do as add the following script to your `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then it would be simple as:

```
$("#clickedElementThatWillHide").click(function(){
    $("span").hide();
  });
```

For more examples checkout [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Vanilla Javascript without using big library

```
<p>
  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Toggle Div</a>
</p>
<div  id="example">
  <ul><a href="bashEmulator.html">Bash Shell Emulator</a></ul>
  <ul><a href="bashShellUseHow.html">How to use bash shell </a></ul>
</div>
<script>
var show = function (elem) {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
};

var hide = function (elem) {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
};

var toggle = function (elem) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (window.getComputedStyle(elem).display === 'block') {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
</script>
```